# Calling a SOAP Service that requires username and password with each call. How should I store the password?

Tags: windows, web-services, security, soap

I'm writing a class in a library that calls a SOAP web service over SSL. The SOAP service requires the username and password to be passed in with each call. This library will be referenced by the server code of a public website. I'm not sure what the standard/best way to store passwords is.

The options I see...

- Hardcode the password as a string in the class
- Store the password in a database
- Store the password in the config file

None of these strike me as both secure and easily updateable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a security specialist and I haven't done any .NET development in ages (so the information might be out of date) but here is a few ideas/advice that might be of help to you.

> Hardcode the password as a string in the class

Don't do that. Your source code is in version control (TFS, Git, whatever) and so will be the username/password, for every developer to see from the moment you check in the code to... forever. In order to secure access to the username/password you are now forced to secure access to the source repository. I imagine all developers need access to the source code but not all need to know about the username/password.

> Store the password in a database

Based on your profile I assume you use SQL server? [See what encryption options are available to SQL server](http://sqlmag.com/database-security/sql-server-encryption-options) if you want to go on that path. Maybe one of them is enough for your use case.

> Store the password in the config file

Again this will likely end up in source control but it's not as bad as the first option since you can [encrypt parts of the config](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx) file (I'm assuming C# based on your profile).

If you have control over the SOAP service maybe you could change it from needing username/passwords to using mutual authentication. You install a certificate on the client (deny exporting the key) and allow calls on the web service only from those clients that have the certificate installed (you can install this on the developer's machine too).

The solution really depends on how important it is to protect this username/password, i.e. the level of security you want (you didn't specify that in your question).

If it's not extremely important, you can have it in the database as your point 2) or in an external file (not committed on source control) referenced from your config and place the file on the server or on dev machines. You then basically control access to the machines (assuming all developer lock their PC when they get up from the keyboard).

If it's really very important to protect this, you could maybe ask on https://security.stackexchange.com/ for better advice than I can give you :).